# Modules installed but not found by Python in Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi  3 with Raspbian and I upgraded python version from 3.7 to 3.8. If I type `python --version` in the terminal the correct version appears as the system version. However none of the modules that I have installed AFTER the version change seem to work. Python gives `ModuleNotFoundError` when trying to import ANY of the modules that I have installed.

I can see the modules with pip freeze but Python seems to not be able to find them.

I followed this instructions to purge 3.7. I reinstalled `pip` after purging python 3.7 but pip as again installed in `/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip`. How can I get rid of 3.7 completely?

Comment: I guess you used pip from the older version to install new modules. Try comparing `pip -V` and `python -m pip -V`

Comment: i have installed python 3.8 removed everything for 3.7 then reinstalled pip but somehow it still does not work. I added a link to the instructions I followed to install python 3.8 and purge 3.7. Even after re-installing pip it was installed in this path `/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip`

Comment: use pip3.8 in command line instead of pip when doing pip install. for example: `pip3.8 install packageName` and not `pip install packageName`. or consider uninstalling the previous python version if you are not using it

Comment: You can use `whereis` on linux to find any offenders, I'd start with `whereis pip3.7` and `whereis python3.7` and for sanity generalize it after those are addressed with `whereis pip` etc.

Comment: `pip` is normal Python script and you can open it in editor and change first line with `shebang` (`#!`) to use `python3.8` instead of `python3.7` - like `#!/usr/bin/python3.8`. But sometimes `pip` can be only link to `pip3.7` and you can remove `pip` and create new `pip` as link to `pip3.8`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to summarize the comments and suggestions from other answers:

The problem I have was caused by the fact that even I had set `Python 3.8` as default and `python -v` was pointing to `Python 3.8` the pip script was installing modules for `Python 3.7`.

The suggested solution was to use pip3.8 (or whatever version someone might have) to install packages for that equivalent Python version and that works good.

Ideally best option if someone wants to have multiple versions of python is to use [pyenv](https://pypi.org/project/pyenv/). You can create multiple virtual environments with multiple python versions.

However  **Do not uninstall the default Python.** I have also tried to uninstall the default `Python 3.7` to avoid having two versions of python 3 and keeping track of which module is installed where. This was a bad idea. I did not know that many Linux distributions have applications which use the default Python. You might get a black screen and who knows what other problems see this discussion [Removed Python 3 on 18.04, how can I fix my system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036249/removed-python-3-on-18-04-how-can-i-fix-my-system)

Answer (score 1):

python3.8 -m pip install SomePackage  # specifically Python 3.8 should work.

More documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html#work-with-multiple-versions-of-python-installed-in-parallel